# VB.Net fires error on saving data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am creating a LMS in VB.Net and SQL Server. The book adding form contains text boxes combo boxes and picture box. When I click the save button It says the following error message

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Saman' to data type int.
```

On the form load the combo boxes populate the data from the entire tables.

Tables and relationship

[image]

Data to be inserted

[image]

Tables with data type

[image]

Error message on saving

[image]

I tried with the following coding

Form load coding

```
Private Sub frmAddBook_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'To load Author details
    Using com As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblBookAuthor", con)

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
        cmbAuthor.DataSource = dt
        cmbAuthor.DisplayMember = "authorFirstName"
        cmbAuthor.ValueMember = "authorFirstName"
        ' con.Close()
    End Using

    'To load Publisher details
    Using com2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblPublisher", con)

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(com2.ExecuteReader)
        cmbPub.DataSource = dt
        cmbPub.DisplayMember = "publisherName"
        cmbPub.ValueMember = "publisherName"

        ' con.Close()
    End Using

    'To load Class details
    Using com3 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblBookClass", con)

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(com3.ExecuteReader)
        cmbClass.DataSource = dt
        cmbClass.DisplayMember = "classDetail"
        cmbClass.ValueMember = "classDetail"
        ' con.Close()
    End Using

    'To load bookshelf details
    Using com4 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblBookShelfDetail", con)

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(com4.ExecuteReader)
        cmbBookShelf.DataSource = dt
        cmbBookShelf.DisplayMember = "shelfDetail"
        cmbBookShelf.ValueMember = "shelfDetail"
        con.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

Save button coding

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    sql = "INSERT INTO tblBookDetail (accessionNo, authorId, title, pages, price, ISBN, noOfCopies, pubId, classId, source, bookShelfNo,bookEdition, bookCoverImg) VALUES (@accNo, @auID, @title, @pages, @price, @ISBN, @noOfCopies, @pubID, @classID, @src, @shlfNo, @edition, @img)"

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    picPhoto.Image.Save(ms, picPhoto.Image.RawFormat)

    con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@accNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtBookID.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@auID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbAuthor.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEdition.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pages", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtPageNo.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtPrice.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ISBN", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtISBN.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@noOfCopies", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtNoOfCopies.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pubID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbPub.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@classID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbClass.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@src", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbSrc.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@shlfNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbBookShelf.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@edition", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtEdition.Text

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("SUCCESS")
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Program Error :*

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Saman' to data
>   type int.

Here, you are having column authorID as datatype integer, then how come you will be able to insert varchar, i.e Name 'Saman'  into it !

*Line of Code that trigger this error :*

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@auID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbAuthor.Text
```

Make sure table column is not integer or change accordingly.

**Edit :**

If want to insert id then :

**replace text with SelectedValue in combobox**

Hope you got the point. Thanks

Comment: I changed all the VarChar to int as in Table (Author table, Publisher table, Shelf table, Class table). It throws another error : "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32."

Comment: Dear @SAKTHY dont change entire column datatype values.. make sure "if you are inserting text or char values , datatype is not int"

Comment: try change tblbookdetail authorid to varchar and check the same code and execute to check if errors come

Comment: I only change in coding as follows. I did not change in database,   

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@auID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cmbAuthor.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pubID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cmbPub.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@classID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cmbClass.Text        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@shlfNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cmbBookShelf.Text

Comment: see, here you are inserting saman into author name right ? ,but the value is being saved into author id. Author id column is integer ! Then how saman will get into that column !

Comment: keep the same code and add some integer value in author name ! your code will insert values without error in that case

Comment: No, by the relationship the data type is int. In the Author combo box it should shows the Name of the author rather than their id. Otherwise the library user is confusing on number. It should shows the Name(Saman) in the combo box while it saving to the book table, it should use the authorid of Saman, Because they are made by relationship.

Comment: but you are using "cmbAuthor.Text" this will not take authorId but name that is shown in combobox

Comment: So, how can I save. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace text with SelectedValue

Comment: I got success. Thank you so much @tharif

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @SAKTHY you can mark it as answer if answer was helpful